# Correct way of querying related tables on Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am using yii-user module in my Yii project for user authentication/authorization. It provides methods for handling superusers. In particular I use the function isAdmin():

```
public static function isAdmin() {
    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        return false;
    ...
}
```

In my project I have the **House** entity, and there are also a new type of users: **HouseAdmins** (and the corresponding house and house_admin tables in DB). So I have 3 types of users:

1. house members: users with login/password but not superusers.
2. house admins: house members which rule a particuar house.
3. superusers: those superusers as the yii-user modules handles them (isAdmin() returns true).

What I need is to create another method (hopefully based on isAdmin()) that returns true if a user is houseAdmin of a particular house. The function would be something like: "return true if the is a tuple in table `house_admin` with values: `user_id=current_user; house_id=Y`"

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about exact DB column names, but you can try this:

```
public function isHouseAdminOf($house_id)
{
   $cur_user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;

   $any = HouseAdmin::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                                    'house_id'=>$house_id, 
                                    'user_id'=>$cur_user_id
                                  ));

   if(isset($any)) 
      return true;

   return false;
}
```